# Browser won't remove cookie

Tags: cookies, browser

I have a cookie with the domain set to something like `my.domain.com`.
Recently I created a new subdomain and needed to share the cookie so I changed the domain of the cookie to be `.domain.com` so the other subdomain could read it.

The problem is most users still have the old cookie and the browsers won't remove it no matter what I send in the response headers.
So now it looks like this:

`"name=my-session-cookie value= domain=my.domain.com path=/ Expires=2024-03-14T07:54:05.000Z`

`"name=my-session-cookie value= domain=.domain.com path=/ Expires=2024-03-14T07:54:05.000Z`

And in the response I'm sending:

`set-cookie: my-session-cookie=; Domain=my.domain.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

`set-cookie: my-session-cookie=; Domain=.domain.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`

But the cookie with domain `my.domain.com` is not updated at all by the browser.

Am I doing something wrong here? I don't understand why the browser won't update the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

It turns out if the domain is `my.domain.com` and cookie has the same domain the `set-cookie` should not set the domain explicitly.

So it should just be
`set-cookie: my-session-cookie=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`